# Is it proper to make a grand-parent key, a primary key, in its grand-child, in a multi-level identifying relationship?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, normalization, composite-primary-key

Asked this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82980/is-it-proper-to-make-a-grand-parent-key-a-primary-key-in-its-grand-child-in-a) a couple of days ago, but haven't gotten many views, let alone a response, so I'm reposting to stackoverflow.

I'm modeling a DB for a conference ticketing system.  In this system **attendees** are members of an **attendee group**, which belong to a **conference**. These relationships are identifying, and therefore FKs must be PKs in the respective children.

My current model:

[image]

**Q**:  Is it proper to have `attendeeGroupConferenceId` FK, as a PK, in the `attendee` table, as *MySQL Workbench* has automatically set up for me?

On one side one would get a performance boost by keeping it in there for quick association at "check in".  *However*, it does not strictly necessary since the combination of `id`, `attendeeGroupId`, and a corresponding lookup of `conferenceId` in the respective `attendeeGroup` table, is enough. (Therefore becomes redundant data.)

To me, it feels like it might violate some form of normalization, but I plan on keeping it in for the speed boost as described. I'm just curious about what proper design says about giving it PK status or not.

Comment: A field (key or otherwise) should generally *never* be included if it can be derived from a query. Also, there is no "performance boost" unless proven by relevant benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need the `attendeeGroupConferenceId` in your `attendee` table. It's redundant and notice that candidate key is the combination of `(attendeeGroupId, personId)`, not the `attendeeGroupConferenceId` alone.
The table `attendee` also seems to violate the [Second normal form (2NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) as it is.

My suggestion is to remove the attribute `attendeeGroupConferenceId`. In any case you can just join the tables in your queries to get extra info rather than keeping an extra attribute.